# How can I fix a corrupted Ambiance theme?

Tags: 12.10, ambiance

As described in [another issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204804/broken-theme-after-upgrading-to-12-10), upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10 may break the Ambiance theme, causing many of the menus and controls to display in a strange grey-on-grey state.

I have checked another user account and the theme appears fine there, so it seems to be a user-specific issue.

What can I do to reset my theme settings to the standard for 12.10? I assume there is some set of config files in my home directory somewhere that are customizing it incorrectly.

(As the linked issue was closed for being "too localized", I'm hoping a general fix can be provided for many similar theme issues.)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall light-themes
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either (though I thought it should)